# How to carry over latest observed record when grouping by on SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

(I've created a similar question before, but I messed it up beyond repair. Hopefully, I can express myself better this time.)

I have a table containing records that change through time, each row representing a modification in Stage and Amount. I need to group these records by Day and Stage, summing up the Amount.

The tricky part is: ids might not change in some days. Since there won't be any record in those days, so I need to carry over the latest record observed.

Find below the records table and the expected result. MRE on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9900673e549cfaab42b5a8c36ea1dcbc) (PostgreSQL)

Records

[image: Records]

Expected Result

[image: Expected Result]

I created this basic visualization to demonstrate how the Amounts and Stages change throughout the days. Each number/color change represents a modification.

[image: Visualization]

The logic behind the expected result can be found below.

**Total Amount by Stage on Day 2**

Id A was modified on Day 2, let's take that Amount: Negotiation 60.

Id B wasn't modified on Day 2, so we carry over the most recent modification (Day 1): Open 10.

Open 10

Negotiation 60

Closed 0

**Total Amount by Stage on Day 3**

Id A wasn't modified on Day 3, so we carry over the most recent modification (Day 2): Negotiation 60.

Id A was modified on Day 3: Negotiation 30

Total Amount by Stage on Day 3

Open 0

Negotiation 90

Closed 0

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: thanks for (yet another) heads-up. I've edited the question and added the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you seem to want the most recent value for each id --- and it only gets counted for the most recent stage.

You can get this using a formulation like this:

```
select d.DateDay, s.stage, coalesce(sh.amount, 0)
from (select distinct sh.DateDay from stage_history sh) d cross join
     (select distinct sh.stage from stage_history sh) s left join lateral
     (select sum(sh.amount) as amount
      from (select distinct on (sh.id) sh.*
            from stage_history sh
            where sh.DateDay <= d.DateDay 
            order by sh.id, sh.DateDay desc
           ) sh
      where sh.stage = s.stage
     ) sh
     on 1=1
order by d.DateDay, s.stage;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0f2bd4775319a2a3621895bf69e439b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I had never worked with lateral joins before, very interesting. For the sake of curiosity: what would be the alternative if they weren't available in the dialect?

Comment: @大朱雀 . . . In this case, you can use a correlated subquery.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for leaving the stage condition ("where sh.stage = s.stage") outside of the innermost query?

Comment: @大朱雀 . . . I don't think it works with the condition in the inner query.  That would get the most recent id for each stage (I think), rather than the most  stage for each id.

Comment: I just realized this is the last query in the db<>fiddle